# How to Obtain Percents? Can I obtain the group Sum and total Sum in the same Query?

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to below. I need to get the percentages for each region, but to obtain it I have to get the total sum because it is not always going to be 100.

```
Customer  Region  Quantity
--------  ------  --------
1         East     10
2         West     10
3         South    10
4         South    10
5         South    10
6         South    10
7         South    10
8         North    10
9         North    10
10        North    10
```

The result should be:

```
Region  Percent
------  -------
West     10% 
East     10%
South    50%
North    30%
```

If I group by Region, I can obtain the sum only for that region, but I need the sum for the entire result.

Comment: select count(customer), sum(qauntity) from mytable

Comment: What DBMS? What version? MySQL? Sql Server 2008? What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery value expression:

```
SELECT
   Region,
   Percent =
      Sum(Quantity) * 100.0
      / (SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM dbo.Table)
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY Region

-- alternate denominator for SQL Server 2005 and up:
/ Sum(Quantity) OVER ()
```

Comment: `SUM(Quantity)`, not `SUM(*)`

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
SELECT 
  region, 
  COUNT(Quantity) / 
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Table1) * 100 AS "ThePercent"
FROM Table1
GROUP BY region;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd6de/3)

This will give you:

```
| REGION | THEPERCENT |
-----------------------
|   East |         10 |
|  North |         30 |
|  South |         50 |
|   West |         10 |
```

If you need to print the `%` for each percent, you should use your RDBMS concatenation way to do so. But you didn't specify what RDBMS you are using, so you have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
SELECT Region, 
       COUNT(Quantity)*100.0/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Your_Table) AS percentage
       FROM Your_Table
WHERE Region IS not null
GROUP BY Region
```

### **[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ff81/2)**

### **OutPut**

```
REGION  PERCENTAGE
--------------------
East    10
North   30
South   50
West    10
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2005+ use OVER clause with aggregation function

```
SELECT Region, SUM(Quantity) * 100 / SUM(SUM(Quantity)) OVER () AS Perc
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Region
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3fe1/2/0)

Comment: tnx ErikE you are absolutely right PARTITION BY excessive in this case;)